# Material components web components mwc-button upload file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, material-design, web-component

I would like to upload a file using mwc-button from the material web components library. How can I combine it with `<input type="file" />`, so that I have inputs upload functionality but with the styling of mwc-button? Below is what I have so far:

```
<input type="file" />
<mwc-button
  label="Upload Data"
  raised
  icon="publish"
  @click=uploadFile
></mwc-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```html
<input id="file-upload" type="file"  hidden/>
<mwc-button
  label="Upload Data"
  icon="publish"
  raised
  @click=${() => {
    const input = document.querySelector("#file-upload");
    input.click();
  }}
  >
</mwc-button>
```